# What should be my syntax for Meteor.call when passing an object to this function?

Tags: javascript, function, meteor, function-call

I am given this instruction:

```
Metor.call("templates.setAsPublicTemplate", itemId: string,
description: string,
imgURL: string,
language: string,
order?: number,
)
```

In which I added this information, but it doesnt seem right and of course it doesnt work, How do I pass this function?

```
Meteor.call("templates.setAsPublicTemplate", {
    itemId: "nbgcnNr4YmXwMWMjP",
    description: "this is the description of my template space bla bla bla",
    imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png",
    language: "en",
    order: 0,
});
```

Comment: I've never used this library myself, but have you tried:

`Meteor.call("templates.setAsPublicTemplate", "nbgcnNr4YmXwMWMjP", "this is the description of my template space bla bla bla", "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png", "en", 0);
`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a TypeScript prototype that you're given. It tells you the types of the function arguments after the colon, but other than that, you call it like every other javascript function:

```
Meteor.call("templates.setAsPublicTemplate", "nbgcnNr4YmXwMWMjP", "this is the description of my template space bla bla bla", "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png", "en", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this library myself so I can't guarantee this is the proper way of calling it, but this is what I believe you should be calling:

```
Meteor.call(
    "templates.setAsPublicTemplate",
    "nbgcnNr4YmXwMWMjP",
    "this is the description of my template space bla bla bla",
    "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png",
    "en",
    0);
```

### Simple example for documentation:

Say you have the following function documentation:

```
function textTostring(text: string) => void;
```

This means that the function `textToString` accepts 1 parameter called `text` (so you know what it represents) and is of type `string` (so you know what type of value to pass), and then it finally returns a number value.

### Being more specific

If you want to call it using an object, so that you name every property manually you could create a wrapper function like so:

```
function meteorCall(data) {
  return Meteor.call("templates.setAsPublicTemplate", 
    data.itemId, 
    data.description, 
    data.imgURL,
    data.language,
    data.order);
}
```

Which you would call as:

```
meteorCall({
    itemId: "nbgcnNr4YmXwMWMjP",
    description: "this is the description of my template space bla bla bla",
    imgURL: "https://res.cloudinary.com/deruwllkv/image/upload/v1625753766/shopping.png",
    language: "en",
    order: 0,
});
```